# Prove that the multiplication operator $M_{f}$ is self-adjoint if and only if $ess\, ran\, f \subset \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Let $M_{f}$ be the multiplication operator on a Hilbert space $L^{2}(X,\mu)$ defined as
$$M_{f}: D(M_{f})\rightarrow L^{2}(X,\mu),\; M_{f}g=fg$$
where $D(M_{f})=\{g\in L^{2}(X,\mu) : fg\in L^{2}(X,\mu) \}$ and $f$ a measurable function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

The essential range of $f$ is defined as $$ess\, ran\, f:=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}:\mu(f^{-1}(B_{\varepsilon}(\lambda)))>0 \text{ for all } \varepsilon >0\}$$
I want to proof that the following statements are equivalent:

i) $M_{f}$ is self-adjoint 
ii) $ess\, ran\, f \subset \mathbb{R}$
iii) $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ almost everywhere

$i) \rightarrow ii)$

No idea yet but I'm thankful for suggestions.

$ii) \rightarrow iii)$

We need to show that $ess\, ran\, f$ implies the existence of a set $N$ with measure zero such that $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x \in X\setminus N$.

Set $A:=ess\, ran\, f$. Take $\lambda \in A^{C}$. By the definition of the essential range of $f$ there exists an $\varepsilon_{\lambda} >0$ with $\mu\left(f^{-1}(B_{\varepsilon_{\lambda}}(\lambda)\right)=0$. For $A^{C}$ countable we could conclude that
$$
\mu\left(
\bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in A^{C}}f^{-1}B_{\varepsilon_{\lambda}}(\lambda))
\right)
=
0$$
using the $\sigma-$sub-additivity of measures.

For $A^{C}$ uncountable we cannot uses this. I assume that one could proof $\mu(A^{C})=0$ by finding a compact superset of $A^{C}$ which can be decomposed into a countable number of sets with measure zero. However I was not able to find such a set.

Any suggestions?

$iii) \rightarrow i)$

By assumption there exists a set $N$ wiht $\mu(N)=0$ such that $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x \in X\setminus N$. The self-adjointness then follows using $f(x)=\overline{f(x)}$ for $x \in X\setminus N$:
$$\begin{align}
\langle M_{f}g,h \rangle &= \int_{X}\overline{(M_{f}g)(x)}h(x) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)\\
&=
\int_{X}\overline{f(x)g(x)}h(x) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)\\
&=
\int_{X\setminus N}\overline{f(x)g(x)}h(x) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)\\
&=
\int_{X\setminus N}\overline{g(x)}f(x)h(x) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)\\
&=
\int_{X\setminus N}\overline{g(x)}(M_{f}h)(x) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)\\
&=
\int_{X}\overline{g(x)}(M_{f}h)(x) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)\\
&=\langle g,M_{f}h\rangle
\end{align}$$

Thus $\langle M_{f}g,h \rangle=\langle g,M_{f}h\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try proving (i)<->(iii) and (ii)<->(iii).

You can get (i)->(iii) from the same identity you derived in (iii)->(i).  If $M_f$ is self-adjoint, then you have $\int \overline{f} \overline{g} h = \int f \overline{g} h$.  In other words, $\int (\overline{f} - f) \overline{g} h = 0$ for arbitrary $g,h$, from which it follows that $\overline{f} - f = 0$ almost everywhere, i.e. $f \in \mathbb{R}$ almost everywhere.

For your (ii)->(iii), you have an open cover of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ by open sets of $\mu \circ f^{-1}$-measure zero.  Now $\mathbb{C}$, like every separable metric space, has the [Lindelöf property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space), so this open cover admits a countable subcover.

The implication (iii)->(ii) is immediate since $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed set.

Comment: Thanks. (i)$\Rightarrow$ (iii) and (ii)$\Rightarrow$ (iii) are clear now, but how does the closedness of $\mathbb{R}$ imply (ii)?

Comment: @bayes2021: $\mathbb{R}$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$, so its complement is open, so every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{C}$ has a neighborhood $B_\epsilon(\lambda)$ which does not intersect $\mathbb{R}$ and thus has $\mu(f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(\lambda))=0$.  That means $\lambda \notin \operatorname{ess sup} f$.

Comment: (ii)$\Rightarrow$ (iii) Using the Lindelöf property every element of the subcover has measure zero (wrt. $\mu \circ f^{-1}$) and therefore the countable union also has measure zero. Is it also possible to prove this step using that $\mathbb{C}$ is second-countable? $\bigcup_{\lambda \notin ess\, ran\, f}B_{\varepsilon_{\lambda}}(\lambda)$ is an open set and therefore a countable collection of sets with $\|C_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}=\bigcup_{\lambda \notin ess\, ran\, f}B_{\varepsilon_{\lambda}}(\lambda)$ exist. However I couldn't proof that $\mu(f^{-1}(C_{n})=0$

Comment: @bayes2021: You have to choose the $C_n$ with a little more care.  For every $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ there is a ball $B_\epsilon(\lambda)$ with $\mu(f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(\lambda)) = 0$.  Now if $\{U_n\}$ is your countable base, then there is some $n = n(\lambda)$ with $\lambda \in U_{n(\lambda)} \subset B_\epsilon(\lambda)$, which means in particular that $\mu(f^{-1}(U_{n(\lambda)})) = 0$.  Now the countable union of all these $U_{n(\lambda)}$ covers $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That's the point. If I could show $U_{n} \subset B_{\varepsilon}(\lambda)$, $\mu\left(f^{-1}(U_{n})\right)=0$ follows. That $n$ exists such that $\lambda\in U_{n(\lambda)}$ is clear. However I do not see how $U_{n(\lambda)}\subset B_{\varepsilon}(\lambda)$ can be satisfied for every $\lambda$ since the $\lambda$'s are uncountable while $U_{n}$ is a countable family.

Comment: @bayes2021: That's the definition of second countable: for every point $\lambda$ and every open set $V$ containing $\lambda$, there is one of your basic open sets $U_n$ with $\lambda \in U_n \subset V$.  Of course, a given $U_n$ may have to serve as the $U_{n(\lambda)}$ for lots and lots of different $\lambda$.

Comment: @bayes2021: To say it another way, second countable implies that *each* of your open balls $B_\epsilon(\lambda)$ can be written as a union of sets $U_{n_i}$ from your countable base.  In particular each $U_{n_i}$ is contained in $B_\epsilon(\lambda)$, and necessarily one of them contains $\lambda$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.